# Сортировка двумерного массива по одинаковым значениям

Tags: php

Есть двумерный массив:

```php
$array = [
['key1'=>'string1_1', 'key2'=>'string2_1', 'key3'=>'string3_1'], 
['key1'=>'string1_2', 'key2'=>'string2_2', 'key3'=>'string3_2'], 
['key1'=>'string1_3', 'key2'=>'string2_3', 'key3'=>'string3_3'],
...
['key1'=>'string1_1', 'key2'=>'string2_5', 'key3'=>'string3_9'],
['key1'=>'string1_1', 'key2'=>'string2_1', 'key3'=>'string3_1']
];
```

Необходимо отсортировать массив так, чтобы если у вложенных массивов есть одинаковые ключ-значения, то они находятся рядом по ключам примерно вот так:

```php
$array = [
   ['key1'=>'string1_1', 'key2'=>'string2_1', 'key3'=>'string3_1'], 
   ['key1'=>'string1_1', 'key2'=>'string2_5', 'key3'=>'string3_9'], 
   ['key1'=>'string1_3', 'key2'=>'string2_3', 'key3'=>'string3_3'],
   ['key1'=>'string1_3', 'key2'=>'string2_7', 'key3'=>'string3_3'],
   ...
   ['key1'=>'string1_2', 'key2'=>'string2_2', 'key3'=>'string3_2']
   ];
```

Понимаю, что есть решение "в лоб", но хотелось бы и более быстрое решение этой проблемы.
Суть в том что из этого массива будет строится таблица, эта сортировка необходима для объединения ячеек с одинаковыми значениями, для этого строки должны быть рядом.
Добавляю пример решения "в лоб", но только по первому ключу

```php
$sub_array = [];
foreach($array as $key => $row)
{
    if(isset($sub_ar['key1'][$row['key1']]))
    {
        $sub_ar['key1'][$row['key1']][$key] = $key;
    }
    else
    {
        $sub_ar['key1'][$row['key1']] = [$key=>$key];
    }
}
$ar_check = []
foreach($sub_ar['key1'] as $array_second)
{
    foreach($array as $row)
    {
        $ar_check[] = $ar[$row];
    }
}
```

Comment: *Понимаю, что есть решение "в лоб"* - Ну вот и приведите его, глядишь, и задача понятнее станет

Comment: `usort($array, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['key1'], $b['key1']); });`

Comment: @InDevX а вы понимаете, почему в результате string1_2 после string1_3 ?

Comment: @splash58 об этом речи не было и по-этому комментарий. тут странно всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последовательно сравниваем ключи, пока не найдутся разные. И такую функцию отлаем в [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    $keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
    foreach($keys as $x) {
        if ($res = $a[$x] <=> $b[$x]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

usort($array, "compare");
print_r($array);
```